# How to add dynamic row value from button to tableview in javafx

Tags: java, javafx, xampp, scenebuilder, javafx-11

I am working on a POS system using Javafx , and I'm trying to set value to a tableview after clicking a button which was generated by MySQL data to. But any time I click the button let say coffee  it's fetching all data from instead.

Here is the code

```
public void allItems(String EnterItemName) throws SQLException {
    String query ="SELECT `id`,`name`,`rate`FROM `products` WHERE `category`= '"+EnterItemName+"' ORDER BY `rate` ";
    buttonList = new ArrayList<>(); //our Collection to hold newly created Buttons
    pst = con.prepareStatement(query);
    rs = pst.executeQuery();
    while (rs.next()){
        String id = rs.getString(1);
        String name = rs.getString(2);
        String rate = rs.getString(3);
        ArrayList<String> content= new ArrayList<>();
        content.add(id);
        content.add(name);
        content.add(rate);
        JFXButton buttonFist = new JFXButton( content.get(1)+"\n "+content.get(2) +" $");
        buttonFist.setStyle(" -fx-background-color:  #005d9a;" +
                " -fx-pref-height: 50px;\n" +
                "-fx-pref-width: 150px;" +
                "-fx-text-fill:#ffffff;"+
                "-fx-alignment:CENTER;");
        buttonFist.setOnAction(event1 ->  {
            btnClicked ++;
           try {
               double priceProd = Double.parseDouble(content.get(2)) ;
                      lblProdPrice.setText(String.valueOf(priceProd));
               int qte = btnClicked;
               lblProdQte.setText(String.valueOf(qte));
               double total = qte * priceProd;
               lblTotalPrice.setText(String.valueOf(total));
                dataCollection = getObsArticles();
                colIDArticle.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("item_Code"));
                colArticleName.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("item_Description"));
                colArticlePrice.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("item_Price"));
                colArticleQt .setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("item_Qty"));
                colArticleTotal.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("amount"));
                tableArticle.setItems(dataCollection);
                String order_Id=content.get(0);
                String itemCode=content.get(0);
                int qty= btnClicked;
                double unitPrice= Double.parseDouble(content.get(2));
                OrderDetail od=new OrderDetail(order_Id,itemCode,qty,unitPrice);
                orderDetailList.add(od);
                            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            currentTable =tableArticle.getItems();
            String currentProdId = String.valueOf(content.get(0));
            if (event1.getSource()!=content.get(0)){
                               double value =Double.parseDouble( content.get(2));
                if (event1.getSource().equals(content.get(0))){
                }else if (event1.getSource()!=content.get(0)){
                    int frstindex  = event1.getSource().toString().indexOf("<b>");
                    double Gtotal = Double.parseDouble(txtTotalPOS.getText())  + value;
                    txtTotalPOS.setText(Double.toString(Gtotal));
                    txtSubTotalPOS.setText(Double.toString(Gtotal));
                }
            }
            for (OrderTableModel product: currentTable){
                if (product.getItem_Code().equals(currentProdId)){
                    product.setItem_Code(content.get(0));
                    product.setItem_Description(content.get(1));
                    product.setItem_Price(Double.parseDouble(content.get(2)));
                    product.setItem_Qty(btnClicked);
                    tableArticle.setItems(currentTable);
                    break;
                }
            }
        });
        buttonList.add(buttonFist);
    }
    hboxx.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
    hboxx.getChildren().clear();
    hboxx.getChildren().addAll(buttonList);
 }
```

Point of sale:
[image]

Comment: I have formatted the code by splitting it *before* blocks of spaces. Hopefully that split was done correctly. Please check that I have done it correctly.  In future it would be better if you format your code correctly when you write a question.

Comment: I now think you need to add more details to the question. Describe the output you are getting, describe what you want and explain how the two are different. Please read about [mcve].

Comment: I want that when I click the button like "Chicken 10$  " to be added on the tableview and if I click it twice the same button the quantity have to  double. After that if a client want to add a soda you click on button "Soda 2$" and the systems add sum up every order of the client and those orders are being added on the tableview

Comment: There's also an image I attended to the questions

Comment: When I wrote *"add more details to the question"* I meant you should [edit] the question to add those details. I know there is an image, but the question should explain things in text. Images should generally only be used to emphasise a point. Please take the [tour] and read the [help] pages to learn how to write a good question for this site.

Comment: One thing that looks strange to me is the location of `ArrayList<String> content= new ArrayList<>();`. I think it should be outside of the `while-loop`. Beyond that, your code is confusing. Separate your database code. Split tasks into their own methods. You have too much going on in `allItems`.